# I can't get a response back from an Ajax call to a PHP page

Tags: php, ajax

This is my javascript for sending the request to the php page. But I can't get the response when I use the conditional if statement with the `$_REQUEST` variable

```
function getNumberOfShareHolders()
{
  var dataString = "GNOSH";
  alert(dataString);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'chartJs.php',
    dataType: "json",
    dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
       if(data) 
       {
        alert(data);
       } 
      else {

      }     
    } 
  });
}
```

Here's the php code

```
if(empty($_REQUEST['GNOSH'])) {
echo json_encode("request");
} 
else 
{
echo json_encode("No request");
}
```

Comment: Hi @Shwan, welcome. You must be more specific on what's happening with your code. Error messages? Error logs?

Comment: You did not specify what data to send to the server

Comment: @EliasSoares, there is no any error messages, i just can't get into the if statement

Comment: add on the ajax setup , `data : {GNOSH:dataString}`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile i'm running an MySQL query that will bring back everything, so there is no need for passing any data to the server

Comment: What exactly do you think `$_REQUEST['GNOSH']` does then?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified a `data` property at all, so you aren't passing any data for jQuery to put in the HTTP request.

You've included a property named `dataString` in your options (which is ignored) and given it the value `GNOSH`.

You need a property called `data` with a value that is an object, then that object needs a property named `GNOSH` with *some value*. What that value is doesn't really matter as you are testing for truthfulness.

```
dataType: "json",
data: { [dataString]: 1 },
cache: false,
```

Comment: Also, it looks like the condition in the PHP code is reversed and it should be `if(!empty($_REQUEST['GNOSH']))` if I'm understanding what he's trying to achieve...

@Shwan exclamation mark is shorthand for `not`